# Django - Unable to find object using pk (Matching query DoesNotExist)

Tags: python, django, django-views

Whenever I try to create a "Tour" for a "User" I get this error:
"DoesNotExist at /add-tour/FAjK5CryF8/ - User matching query does not exist."

Specifically the problems seems to come from this line of code:

```
user = User.objects.get(pk=pk)
```

**models.py**

```
class Tour(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tour_date = models.DateField(default=date.today)
    tour_fans = models.ForeignKey(FanAccount, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user} del {self.tour_date}"
```

**views.py**

```
def tour_new(request, pk):
    user = User.objects.get(pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = TourForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.tour_fans = request.user
            form.instance.user = user
            instance.save()
            form.save()
            return render(request, "tour.html", {"form": TourForm(), "success": True})
    else:
        form = TourForm()
    return render(request, "tour.html", {"form": form})
```

For "User" I'm using a custom Primary Key (ShortUUID).
I'm new to Python and Django so it may be something easily solvable, but after hours of attempts I seem unable to solve it.

Comment: You may want to see the value of `pk` when you are getting the error. And you may want to add `User` model too, to the question if its a custom user model.

Comment: Show us urls.py file and how are you calling tour_new view

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure your user instance does exist, so you should instead of `user = User.objects.get(pk=pk)`call user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=pk), then you need to pass user as an instance:

```
if request.method == "POST":
   form = TourForm(request.POST, instance=user)
```

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work: `DoesNotExist at /add-tour/1/ - User matching query does not exist.`

Comment: Can you print(user) in console?